# How to use Python to make plots in Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file, it has two columns, 'Time' and 'Sample'. I want to make a line graph of 'Sample' VS 'Time'.

I tried:

```
excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]


chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})


chart.add_series({'values': ["Sheet 1", 1, 1, 2000, 1]})
chart.add_series({'values': ["Sheet 1", 1, 2, 2000, 2]})

worksheet.insert_chart('P2', chart)

workbook.close`
```

The code runs, but I can't open the excel file. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! However I still can't open the file. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

- The chart series refers to a sheet called "Sheet 1" (with space) but the code creates a worksheet called "Sheet1" (no space).
- The dataframe isn't written to an Excel file with `df.to_excel()`
- The `close()` should be on the `writer` and not the `workbook`. That isn't a critical error but best to avoid it.

With these issues fixed you should get the output you expect:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Data1": [10, 20, 30, 10, 19, 35, 40],
        "Data2": [20, 10, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45],
    }
)

excel_file = "test.xlsx"
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine="xlsxwriter")

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

chart = workbook.add_chart({"type": "line"})

(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

chart.add_series({"values": [sheet_name, 1, 1, max_row, 1]})
chart.add_series({"values": [sheet_name, 1, 2, max_row, 2]})

worksheet.insert_chart(1, 4, chart)

writer.close()
```

Output:

[image]